# How to make WebView content load faster?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiwebview

I'm using the code below to load a text file content into a WebView but each time the method is called the content takes some time to load. Any idea of a caching policy I can use in this context to make it load faster ?

```
- (void)displayContent 
{

    @try {
         NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"about-us" ofType:@"txt"];
         [web_view loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithContentOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] baseURL:nil];
   } @catch(NSException e) {
         NSLog(@"%@",e);
   }
}
```

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just set a `fileContents` string to `nil` and 'lazy instantiate' it with the resource contents in your main bundle?

For instance, your code could then be:

```
- (void)displayContent
{
    @try
    {
        if (fileContents == nil)
        {
            NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"about-us" ofType:@"txt"];
            fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        }
        [web_view loadHTMLString:fileContents baseURL:nil];
    }
    @catch(NSException e)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", e);
    }
}
```

No reason to overcomplicate things unless you have other particular concerns.